# Is there some hardware acceleration default in OpenLayers 3.0 that can be disabled?

Tags: windows, openlayers, fedora, qwebview

I've been having a lot of fun with OpenLayers recently (http://www.nufosmatic.com), and tripped over nasty which isn't resolving for me. I'm not actually even sure where the issue lies.

I need to generate some static displays: I'm replacing Java everywhere and migrating to Python and JavaScript. I found a very nice example of taking screenshots of a webpage here:

http://webscraping.com/blog/Webpage-screenshots-with-webkit/

It uses Qt "QWebview" to render then dump the webpage. It was working for posted OpenLayers 2 examples from Windows 7 x86_64 (Python 2.7.6 x86) and Linux Fedora 20 (python 2.7.5) running under Virtual Box on Windows XP x86.

Then this week OpenLayers 3 was released, and I, of course, tried those new examples (the OL 2 example Git page has disappeared, but the 2.10 examples appear to work).

I get the following error diagnostics out of the code I've posted below:

```
$ python webscrape_olprob.py
2.0 example
loaded the Generic plugin
saving simple_2_0.0.png
3.0 example
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
saving simple_3_0.0.png
```

There seems to be some relationship between hardware acceleration and this particular error ("failed to load driver: swrast).

I'd like to validate that OL3 is (sorta/kinda/totally/not) broken on Windows as well. Unfortunately, my Windows 7 environment in which I set this up for testing is remote from me for the foreseeable future (I hate computers that require a person to be in front of it to work).

I'm posting here because this forum demonstrates superior diversity and this problem could be Qt/QWebview, VirtualBox, Fedora 20, or OpenLayers. Given that there is not really that much difference between the 2.0 "OSM" and 3.0 "simple" aka "OSM" examples, my money is on OpenLayers having a hardware acceleration requirement that (1) can't be turned off [and that would be bad] or (2) can be turned off but nobody has complained about that yet so pointers to the docs to turn this off haven't yet shown up in the various fora.

```
 #
 # http://webscraping.com/blog/Webpage-screenshots-with-webkit/
 #

 import sys
 import time
 from PyQt4.QtCore import *
 from PyQt4.QtGui import *
 from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

 class Screenshot(QWebView):
 def __init__(self):
 self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 QWebView.__init__(self)
 self._loaded = False
 self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)

 def capture(self, url, output_file):
 self.load(QUrl(url))
 self.wait_load()
 # set to webpage size
 frame = self.page().mainFrame()
 self.page().setViewportSize(frame.contentsSize())
 # render image
 image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
 painter = QPainter(image)
 frame.render(painter)
 painter.end()
 print 'saving', output_file
 image.save(output_file)

 def wait_load(self, delay=0):
 # process app events until page loaded
 while not self._loaded:
 self.app.processEvents()
 time.sleep(delay)
 self._loaded = False

 def _loadFinished(self, result):
 self._loaded = True

 s = Screenshot()

 print "2.0 example"
 s.capture('http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/osm.html', 'simple_2_0.0.png')

 print "3.0 example"
 s.capture('http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/simple.html', 'simple_3_0.0.png')
```

is a

UPDATE - Ran this on Windows and did not get any warning (instanced below from a Cygwin shell):

```
 webkit/webscrape> c:/python27/python webscrape_olprob.py
 2.0 example
 saving simple_2_0.0.png
 3.0 example
 saving simple_3_0.0.png
```

However, the 2.0 example rendered a map:

[image: 2.0 example]

and the 3.0 example did not:

[image: 3.0 example]

So 3.0 is still having issues on Windows... since 3.0 was just released, I think I shall walk away...

I need to test the renderer suggestion, which necessarily requires my changing the posted examples. I'm disinclined because (1) I need to use Canvas because of the OL feature I'm targetting and (2) I'm looking for some way of affecting rendering from the ENGINE since this is QWebView that is doing the rendering...

Answer (score 0):

You can "hint" to ol.Map, what renderer you prefer to use through the `renderer` option property

- `ol.RendererHints.canvas` for HTML5 canvas
- `ol.RendererHints.dom` for the classic DOM-based approach
- `ol.RendererHints.webgl` for WebGL

According to the [API documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html), ol.Map should correctly determine the appropriate renderer to use unless you override by specifying the renderer yourself. Perhaps the renderer support testing in ol.Map may be confused under QtWebView.

Comment: Thank you. I just sent through an exercise with comparing the behavior of renderers.